# Work around for 'missing column: channel_id' in database when creating a belongsTo relationship - Grails 3.0.2

Tags: grails, groovy, foreign-keys, grails-orm

**Context**:
I am made to work with a particular set of tables, one of which is a represents channels, the other a set relationships between the channels. The channels have a hasMany relationships with the links and the links belongTo the channels.

**Problem**:
The problem arises from the fact that Grails desires a channel_id column in the link table, of which there isn't, that data is represented in another which has been given another name, linkFrom.

**Question**:
My question, which I intend to be generic and not about the particular implementation, is how can you point Grails to look for a different column as the foreign key in a belongsTo relationship, instead of the column [owner_table_id] as per its convention?

Comment: [`joinTable`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) is what you need I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this in your Link Domain:

```
class Link{
    ...
    static belongsTo = [channel: Channel]
    static mapping = {
        channel column: "linkFrom"
    }
}
```